# How to overlap and align the :after and :before pseudo element text content to the center of a DIV?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to follow some answered questions here, but i'm not able to get the result.

```css
body {
  background-color: #202;
}

.SysCard{
  min-width: 10ch;
  min-height: 8rem;
  position: relative; /* creates a new reference for absolute positioning of ::after */
  border: 1px solid lime;
  border-radius: 8px;  
}

.SysCard:after, .SysCard:before{
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;

  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);

  border: 1px solid yellow;  /* debug border */
}

.SysCard:after{
  content: "\25CF";
  color: #F80;
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px #F80;
  color: #8FF;
}

.SysCard:before {
  content: "|";
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  color: #8FF;
  text-shadow: 0 0 30px #8FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="SysCard"></div>
```

I'm trying to align the text of the :before and :after element of a DIV to his center (so, overlapping them), without recurring to add borders and padding of a specific amount of pixels.

The relevant part of the CSS, which i borrowed from StackOverflow answers and then adapted should be:

```css
    .SysCard:after, .SysCard:before{
      font-size: 2.2rem;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin: 0; padding: 0;

      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      top: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
      transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
```

Is it possible to align the text in the very center of the DIV? If yes, how?

Comment: If your code is very long, only post enough code in the snippet to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D ok, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use `inset:0` (as a shorthand for top, right, bottom, left) to make your pseudo elements the same size as their container, then use grid (or flexbox) to center their content.

```css
body {
  background-color: #202;
}

.SysCard{
  min-width: 10ch;
  min-height: 8rem;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid lime;
  border-radius: 8px;  
}

.SysCard:after, .SysCard:before{
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  position: absolute;
  display:grid;
  inset:0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.SysCard:after{
  content: "\25CF";
  color: #F80;
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px #F80;   
}

.SysCard:before {
  content: "|";
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  color: #8FF;
  text-shadow: 0 0 30px #8FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="SysCard"></div>
```